# Toggle pause with key in HTML5 game

Tags: javascript, html, keydown, keycode

I want to make a function for a html5 game to pause and unpause with the keyboard key <kbd>p</kbd>. I can get the game to pause while pressing <kbd>p</kbd>, but not to unpause while pressing <kbd>p</kbd> again. What am I doing wrong here?

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', pauseGameKeyHandler, false);

function pauseGameKeyHandler(e) { 
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    switch(keyCode){ 
        case 80: //p
        togglePause();
        break; 
    }
}

function togglePause() {
    if ( paused = true ) {
        pauseTime = Date.now();
        var pausedElement = document.getElementById( 'paused' );

        if( pausedElement ) {
            pausedElement.style.width = world.width + 'px';
            pausedElement.style.height = world.height + 'px';
        }

        document.body.className = 'paused';
    } else if ( paused = false ) {
        var wasPaused = paused;
        paused = false;
        time += Date.now() - pauseTime;

        if( wasPaused ) {
            timeLastFrame = Date.now();
            animate();
        }

        document.body.className = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if(paused = true)` sets the variable `paused` to `true` - therefore every time you enter the method you're setting the variable to `true`, so you'll never unpause your game.  Use the double equal signs `==` in your `if` and `else if` statements.  Or you can just say `if(paused)` and `else if(!paused)` to avoid the possible mistake of using assignment instead of comparison.

Also, the overall logic to your method seems a little off.  This is basically what you have.

```
function togglePause() {
    if (paused) { // already paused

    // set the game state to paused

  } else if (!paused) {

    var wasPaused = paused; // you already know it will be set to false

    paused = false; // re-setting the game to paused...

    // restart the game...

  }
}
```

It should be more like this

```
function togglePause() {
    if (paused) { // Already paused
    // restart the game!
    paused = false; // Game was restarted, so you're not paused anymore
  } else{ // Only other option is the game isn't paused, means currently playing
    // pause the game!
    paused = true; // Game was paused, so you're now paused
  }
}
```

The logic and code for unpausing and pausing should just be added into the spots where I only had it as a comment.

Comment: Thanks! But the only thing that does is some funky stuff with my time indicator, and no pause-unpause at all.

Comment: See my edit - let me know if you see how you had things a little backwards.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

```
function pauseGameKeyHandler(e) { 
      var keyCode = e.keyCode;
      switch(keyCode){ 
        case 80: //p
          togglePause();
          break; 
      }
    }

    function togglePause(e) {
        if (keyCode == 80) {
            pause();
        } else if (!paused) {
            pause();
        } else if (paused) {
            resume();
        }
    };

    function pause() {
        paused = true;
        pauseTime = Date.now();

        var pausedElement = document.getElementById( 'paused' );

        if( pausedElement ) {
            pausedElement.style.width = world.width + 'px';
            pausedElement.style.height = world.height + 'px';
        }

        document.body.className = 'paused';
    }

    function resume() {
        var wasPaused = paused;

        paused = false;
        time += Date.now() - pauseTime;

        if( wasPaused ) {
            timeLastFrame = Date.now();
            animate();
        }

        document.body.className = '';
    }
```

Comment: You implemented the logic I suggested in my answer, and instead of accepting my answer you posted your own...